# Do camera modules from electronics vendors require a lens?

Tags: diy

I'm looking an an electronic 'build it' style project using this camera:

[MT9T112 MI-SOC3132 3.1Mp HD CMOS Camera Module /w Adapter Board](http://www.uctronics.com/mt9t112-mi-soc3132-31mp-hd-cmos-camera-module-adapter-board-jpeg-out-p-1440l.html)

I'm a little confused about whether I need a lens and where I would even buy a lens for a camera this small. I understand 'do I need a lens' is basically going to be answered with 'it depends what you want to see' so let me add a little more detail.

I'm looking to get sharp images of the sky at night; stars the moon etc. but I would also like to use the same camera for other projects in the future, so I would probably need to be able to take images of closer things, anything from a few inches to a foot or so.

Comment: A camera without a lens is a [pinhole camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera). Pretty much anything more sophisticated than that and you need a lens of some kind.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling that's right, and a `lens` can be used in a fairly broad sense, eg a telescope could act as a lens, as per @DrMoishe's answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this "camera module" does not have a lens (though from the illustration it seems to have an IR-blocking filter). There are [lenses](http://www.uctronics.com/ls-20150-28mm-focal-length-m12xp05-camera-lens-p-1855l.html) for the module on the same page, though they do not appear to have diaphragm, mechanical shutter or electronic focus mechanism.

The [Micron spec sheet](http://www.uctronics.com/download/MT9T111_MT9T112_DS_A.pdf) indicates that it *would* be feasible for the module to control a lens with electronic focus mechanism. However, if your interest is astrophotography, the lens can be manually set to infinity.

With the f 2.8 lens, this module should easily take pictures of the moon with the 0.44 V/lux responsivity, but that might be a bit short of the responsivity needed to capture faint nebulae or dim stars. However, you might skip using a lens and simply place the module at the focal plane of an inexpensive reflecting telescope. You'll need a clock drive, too, unless you just want to capture star trails or the moon.